# Does VS Code install some extensions automatically?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I noticed that I have many extensions installed that I don't recall manually installing, e.g. isort, jupiter cell tags, etc.

I only installed the "python" and "jupyter notebooks" extensions myself. Those others seem to be installed later without my knowledge.

Does VS Code install extensions automatically somehow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

##### To answer the general question

Yes, VS Code does come with some extensions installed "out-of-box". It calls those extensions "Built-In" extensions. If you open the extension page of one of those extensions, it will say:

> Notice: This extension is bundled with Visual Studio Code. It can be disabled but not uninstalled.

One example of this is the `vscode.typescript-language-features` extension. You can get a list of all running with the `Developer: Show Running Extensions` command. It's kind of hard to find them otherwise, since they don't normally show up in the extensions sidebar.

You can find a list of most (all?) of such extensions [in the VS Code Github repo](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/tree/main/extensions), along with their source code.

##### In your particular case, you misunderstood something

The Python and Jupyter extensions you installed are [extension packs](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2017/03/07/extension-pack-roundup). They include isort and Jupyter Cell Tags (as well as others).

You can see for yourself.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python:

> The Python extension will automatically install the Pylance, Jupyter and isort extensions to give you the best experience when working with Python files and Jupyter notebooks.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-toolsai.jupyter:

> The Jupyter Extension will automatically install the following extensions by default to provide enhanced Jupyter notebook experiences in VS Code.
>
> - Jupyter Keymap - to provide Jupyter-consistent keymaps
> - Jupyter Notebook Renderers - to provide renderers for MIME types such as latex, plotly, vega, etc.
> - Jupyter Cell Tags and Jupyter Slide Show - to provide the ability to tag cells in notebooks and support for presentations

Comment: Many thanks. I have a few vscode installations and can't remember well myself. It seems back in the days it was not extensions pack. Maybe I installed the pack but didn't pay attention what had been installed as a result.